# What is derivative of a function at a particular point a function of?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I need to prove/disprove the following statement:

If $f: \Bbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^n$ is not a constant function, then $Df(x)$ is a one to one function for some $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$.

Here $Df(x)$ denotes the derivative of $f$ at $x$.

First of all, I didn't understand the statement itself.

What is $Df(x)$ a function of in order to check its injectivity?

Is it defined as $Df(x) : \Bbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^n$ defined as

$Df(x)(u) = Df(x).u$ for all $u \in \Bbb{R}^n$

where . denotes the ordinary multiplication of matrices.

Comment: $Df$ will actually be an $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: Yeah..I am sorry..I can't see it where have I written it is not?

Comment: How will I check the injectivity when I don't even know what is it a function  of?

Comment: I think you understand it right. $Df(x)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and can be represented by matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Koro..is it that if I take $f(x) = x$. And then $Df(x)$ will be 1 which is not injective no matter how is it defined?

Comment: @Koro I think the statement is true for $n=1$ (assuming that we have $f\in C^1$). The contrapostive would be "If $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x$ then $f$ is constant," which is true.

Comment: @TrevorNorton..Thanks

Comment: @Koro..But $f(x) = x$ is also non-constant

Comment: @Koro..$f'(x)$ is not one-one considering it as a function of $x$. Here in the question, x is fixed

Comment: @Gitika: Ah I see. Your question statement ready one -one for some $x\in \mathbb R^n$. I didn't see that. In that case, I'll  delete my comments.

Comment: @Koro..I see it now..$f(x) = x$ will also not work. I think TrevorNorton was right

Comment: @Koro..Any example to disprove the above statement?

Comment: @TrevorNorton..Any example to disprove the statement?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, for a differentiable function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$, given a point $a\in \Bbb{R}^n$, the quantity $Df(a)$, or $Df_a$ as I prefer to write it, is itself a linear transformation $Df_a:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$, so this eats a vector $\xi\in\Bbb{R}^n$ and gives you an output $Df_a(\xi)\in \Bbb{R}^m$, and of course linearity here refers to the mapping $\xi\mapsto Df_a(\xi)$ NOT the mapping $a\mapsto Df_a$; this second mapping is not necessarily linear.

Or of course, once you choose a basis (usually the "standard" basis) for $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}^m$, you can think in terms of matrices; $Df_a$ is represented by an $m\times n$ matrix $f'(a):= [Df_a]_{\text{standard bases}}$.

The statement is true for $n=m=1$ because of the mean-value theorem, but is it true more generally? (think of functions which change only in one direction, or even simpler, think of what happens when $f$ itself is a linear transformation).

Answer (score 0):

The Fréchet derivative is the usual notion of derivative in Banach spaces as the Euclidean spaces. If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable then

$$
Df:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m),\quad x\mapsto Df(x)
$$

where $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ is the space of linear functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$, so for each $x\in \Bbb R ^n$ we have that $Df(x)$ can be represented by a $m\times n$ matrix. That is: for each $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $Df(x)y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ (for some given $x$).

Therefore in the above example $Df(x)$ will be injective if and only if the $m\times n$ matrix representing it have rank equal to $n$. Hope this clarify your mind.